# Linux File IO - Multithreading performance - writing to different files

Tags: multithreading, file-io, embedded-linux

I'm currently working on an audio recording application, that fetches up to 8 audio streams from the network and saves the data to the disk (simplified ;) ).
Right now, each stream gets handled by one thread -> the same thread also does the saving work on the disk.

That means I got 8 different threads that perform writes on the same disk, each one into a different file.

Do you think there would be an increase in the disk i/o performance if all the writing work would be done by one common thread (that would sequently write the data into the particular files)?

OS is an embedded Linux, the "disk" is a CF card, the application is written in C.

Thanks for your ideas
Nick

Comment: Is your CF card real Flash memory based or it is microHDD (Microdrive)?

Comment: Its a real Flash, but due to the used controller its recognized as an ATA device by the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer:  Given that you are writing to a Flash disk, I wouldn't expect the number of threads to make much difference one way or another.  But if it did make a difference, I would expect multiple threads to be faster than a single thread, not slower.

The longer answer:

I wrote a similar program to the one you describe about 6 years ago -- it ran on an embedded PowerPC Linux card and read/wrote multiple simultaneous audio files to/from a SCSI hard drive.  I originally wrote it with a single thread doing I/O, because I thought that would give the best throughput, but it turned out that that was not the case.

In particular, when multiple threads were reading/writing at once, the SCSI layer was aware of all the pending requests from all the different threads, and was able to reorder the I/O requests such that seeking of the drive head was minimized.  In the single-thread-IO scenario, on the other hand, the SCSI layer knew only about the single "next" outstanding I/O request and thus could not do that optimization.  That meant extra travel for the drive head in many cases, and therefore lower throughput.

Of course, your application is not using SCSI or a rotating drive with heads that need seeking, so that may not be an issue for you -- but there may be other optimizations that the filesystem/hardware layer can do if it is aware of multiple simultaneous I/O requests.  The only real way to find out is to try various models and measure the results.

My suggestion would be to decouple your disk I/O from your network I/O by moving your disk I/O into a thread-pool.  You can then vary the maximum size of your I/O-thread-pool from 1 to N, and for each size measure the performance of the system.  That would give you a clear idea of what works best on your particular hardware, without requiring you to rewrite the code more than once.

Comment: The network I/O is already decoupled from the disk stuff.  There is one thread handling network IO -> audio messages get queued and written to the disk in an extra thread. (and all this for each recording channel = 16 threads in total) I'll try out your suggestion with the thread-pool, sounds good - thanks. I'll let you know as soon as I get any results.

Comment: If a low priority thread is used for write in RT patch linux, doesn't it make a difference ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's *embedded* linux, I guess your machine has only one processor/core. In this case threads won't improve I/O performance at all. Of course linux block subsystem works well in concurrent environment, but in your case (if my guess about number of cores is right) there can't be a situation when several threads do something simultaneously.

If my guess is wrong and you have more than 1 core, then I'd suggest to benchmark disk I/O. Write a program that writes a lot of data from different threads and another program that does the same from only one thread. The results will show you everything you want to know.

Comment: You are right, there is just one core. Reason for the muliple threads right now is just to have each recording channel as capsulated units. In case of any problems with one channel, hopfully the otherones would still do their work. I guess you are right, that the only way to get an answer is to do some benchmarks. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no big difference between multithreaded and singlethreaded solution in your case, but in case of multithreading you can syncronize between receiving threads and no one thread can affect on other threads in case of blocking in some system call.
 I did particulary the same thing on embedded system, the problem was the high cpu usage when kernel drop many cached dirty pages to the CF, pdflush kernel process take all cpu time in that moment and if you receive stream via udp so it can be skipped because of cpu was busy when udp stream came, so I solved that problem by `fdatasync()` call every time when some not big amount of data received.